# Running makefile results in "/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'"

Tags: wifi, drivers, slackware, modprobe

I'm trying to set up Slackware 14.0 on an Asus EEE PC Flare Series Netbook. Currently I'm trying to configure the wifi. When I enter the following:

```
# iwconfig
```

I get:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Which I've figured out means I don't have the driver for my wireless card installed ([based on this - see the Wireless subheader](http://docs.slackware.com/slackware:beginners_guide#traditional_network_configuration)). I checked `lspci` and here's the info on my network card:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev-01)
```

I managed to find a guide [here](http://abi71.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/install-atheros-ar9285-wireless-network-adapter-on-kernel-3-2-2/) detailing how to install the right driver. I downloaded the tarball from the tutorial, transferred it to the computer running Slackware via usb, extracted it, and ran the commands from the tutorial. When I got to the part where I ran `make`, however, I got the following output:

```
# make
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
./scripts/gen-compat-autoconf.sh config.mk > include/linux/compat_autoconf.h
```

At which point it gets stuck. I eventually cancelled it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and tried to run `make clean`. That also gave the `/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'` error a bunch of times but eventually finished.

At this point I googled a bit and eventually found [this](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-modules/msg00785.html) from 2 years ago which states that the `-l` flag was not implemented in the kernel at that point, but it was on a TODO list. I checked man modprobe and the `-l` flag wasn't mentioned anywhere, nor was there a TOOD section. I also checked the make file and sure enough it tries to invoke `/sbin/modprobe` with the `-l` flag, causing the `make` process to fail.

Has anybody encountered this problem with `modprobe` before? Is there some alternative command I can substitute it with? (I can edit the makefile). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of `modprobe` in Ubuntu 12.04 (from `module-init-tools version 3.16`) *does* have a `-l` option, with description

```
   -l --list List  all  modules  matching the given wildcard (or "*" if no
             wildcard is given).  This option is  provided  for  backwards
             compatibility  and  may  go  away  in future: see find(1) and
             basename(1) for a more flexible alternative.
```

For example,

```
$ modprobe -l 'ath*'
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/ath5k.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_htc.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/ath6kl.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
```

Based on that, it may be possible to replace the command with a command such as `find /path/to/kernel/drivers -name 'xxx'` e.g.

```
$ find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name 'ath*.ko' -type f -printf '%P\n'
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/ath6kl.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_htc.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/ath5k.ko
kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
```

Comment: This seems promising. Will get back once I've tried it. Thanks